# Can I change the port on which my application runs in SAP Web IDE for HANA?

Tags: hana, sap-web-ide

I got a SAP HANA system installed. In the SAP Web IDE for HANA, I run an application, this application runs on port `51066`. My question is: can I change this port to e.g. `80`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a HANA XSA installation, You can change the port on which an application runs. However you can't change it to port 80.

```
ID: demo_mta
_schema-version: '2.0'
description: Demo
version: 0.0.2
modules:
  - name: site-LPH
    type: nodejs
    path: site-web
    parameters:
      memory: 64M
      port: 52000 #Explicitly specify port(s)
      host: site-web
```

You can also specify multiple ports/range.